# How to initialize private fields that are default nil when making the zero value useful?

Tags: go

I am trying to follow the Go proverb "Make the zero value useful" but run into an issue with private fields on my struct that are by default `nil` (like `map`). If the zero value of my struct is to be useful, at some point it needs to initialize the private field. Consider the following situation in which I would like to do away with the constructor for `Response`, and make the zero value of `Response` useful. Obviously the field `bag` (which is a `map[string]interface{}`) needs to be initialized. I try to initialize the field `bag` when the getter `Bag()` is called on Response, which works, and allows for then calling `Set()` on the bag to set a value. But somehow when the response ends up back in the main function, my value gets lost.
I believe the problem is that the initialization that I came up with replaces the pointer on a copy of Response, instead of changing what the pointer points at. So the old pointer still points to `nil`, but I am not sure. How to initialize the private field correctly without the constructor?

```
func main() {
    response := getResponse()
    number := response.Bag().Get("NiceNumber")
    fmt.Println(response.Name, "tells me that your nice number today is:", number)
}

func getResponse() (response Response) {
    response = newResponse() // I am trying to do away with this line.
    response.Name = "MyResponse"
    response.Bag().Set("NiceNumber", 100)
    return
}

type Response struct {
    Name string
    bag  Bag
}

func (r Response) Bag() Bag {
    // I have added this piece of code as an attempt to initialize r.bag
    if r.bag == nil {
        r.bag = Bag(make(map[string]interface{}))
    }
    // ---
    return r.bag
}

type Bag map[string]interface{}

func (b Bag) Set(name string, value interface{}) {
    b[name] = value
}

func (b Bag) Get(name string) interface{} {
    return b[name]
}

// This constructor would be deleted if possible.
func newResponse() Response {
    return Response{
        Name: "",
        bag:  Bag(make(map[string]interface{})),
    }
}
```

Output now is `MyResponse tells me that your nice number today is: 100`, and when I remove the call to the constructor of Response, the output is `MyResponse tells me that your nice number today is: <nil>`.

Comment: *"I believe the problem is that the initialization that I came up with replaces the pointer on a copy of Response, instead of changing what the pointer points at."* -- Yes, you're correct. If you change the method do have a pointer receiver instead, i.e. `func (r *Response) Bag() Bag {`, it should get you the result you expect. But keep in mind that, since `Bag()` modifies its receiver, if your code is passing around `Response` and not `*Response`, it will still end up with inconsistent state.

Comment: That will probably work, but it does not help making the zero value of `Response` useful, namely `Response{}` still does not work correctly. Also it changes the signature of the getResponse() function, which I prefer to avoid if at all possible.

Comment: I think for complex scenarios like this a _constructor_ is the best way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553399/golang-how-to-initialize-a-map-field-within-a-struct or as @mkopriva says, change the methods to accept a ptr receiver

Comment: @mkopriva  I just tried it the way you say and it seems to work, but I do not understand why. How can I call the getter `Bag()` on a non-pointer variable of Response? Could you formulate your suggestion into an answer with a bit of explanation, so I can accept?

Comment: @Bazzz the compiler (or runtime? I forget) does that automatically.

Comment: @mkopriva "the compiler (or runtime? I forget) does that automatically" WHAT??  I thought one of Go's slogans is not to do things autoMAGIC. 

Comment: @Bazzz see [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls): A method call `x.m()` is valid if the method set of (the type of) `x` contains `m` and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of `m`. **If `x` is addressable and `&x`'s method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`**.

Comment: Sometimes sync.Once can help in such tasks. But well, sometimes a constructor functions is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `Bag()` method's receiver to a pointer.

```golang
func (r *Response) Bag() Bag {
    if r.bag == nil {
        r.bag = Bag(make(map[string]interface{}))
    }
    return r.bag
}
```

Note that you can still invoke a pointer-receiver method on a non-pointer value as long as the value is *addressable*. See the docs on [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x
> contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list
> of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is
> shorthand for (&x).m()