# Create instance of struct with values

Tags: go, struct

```
// Valid checks Config data
func (c *Config) Valid() Error {
    // Check mapping.hosts
    for _, raw := range c.Mapping.Hosts {
        if validIP := utils.ValidIP4(raw.IPAddress); !validIP {
            err := new(InvalidIPError)
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

// Error represents errors in config
type Error interface {
    Error() string
}

// InvalidIPError raises when invalid ip provided
type InvalidIPError struct {
    HostRaw HostRaw
}

func (e *InvalidIPError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("You specified invalid IP: %v", e.HostRaw)
}
```

How I can create instance of InvalidIPError with `new` keyword and values to send it to `return` in one line?

For example something like this `return new(InvalidIPError{HostRaw: raw})`

Comment: You can't using `new`, but you don't have to use `new`. Try taking the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498998/how-to-initialize-members-in-go-struct,

Answer (score -1):

```
return &InvalidIPError{HostRaw: raw}
```

Comment: More detail as to *why* this solves the question would be very useful to other readers in the future.